# Fetching SAML response

Tags: apache, tomcat, saml-2.0

I have a simple web application running on tomcat 7 http://idp.nikunj.com:8080/gslab
I have installed Apache and cofigured it with SSL.
My Apache is communicating with tomcat means when I type https://idp.nikunj.com/ it redirect me to http:idp.nikunj.com:8080/gslab

### My httpd-ssl.conf is somethig like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
ServerName idp.nikunj.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "c:/Apache24/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "c:/Apache24/logs/access.log"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:\idpV2.4.4\credentials\idp.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\idpV2.4.4\credentials\idp.key"
<Location />
  AuthType shibboleth
  ShibRequestSetting applicationId gslab
  ProxyPass  http://idp.nikunj.com:8080/gslab/
  ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
  require valid-user
</Location>
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
UseCanonicalName on
</VirtualHost>
```

---

I have configured Shibboleth on apache and configured SSO using salesforce as IDP.
when I hit my apache it redirects me to salesforce. After successful authentication I am redirected to my web application running on Tomcat. Working fine.
I am getting SAMLRespose fine in POST Param.

Now what I need to do is I want to print SAML attributes on my web page.
Please help.

Comment: So can your web app get a hold of the SAMLResponse token? If so, it should be relatively simple to just parse the XML for the AttributeStatement element and iterate over all the attributes. Is there something stopping you from taking this approach?

Comment: I am unable to predict where actually the response is coming? Apache or Tomcat? If its coming towards Apache its relatively easy to fetch the attributes. But if it is coming towards Apache i will have to forward it to tomcat which I am not able to do.

Comment: So http://idp.nikunj.com:8080/gslab is running on TomCat 7 and https://idp.nikunj.com/ is Apache? So if SFDC is returning the token to your TomCat application, then that's where you'd need to parse the token. If I understand your setup correctly - which I may not.

Comment: SAML token is getting returned to Apache.
From Apache I am getting redirected to tomcat well ad good.
I just want to know whether the token is getting forwarded to tomcat or it is with Apache only?
If it is with Apache, how to forward it to tomcat?